# Can vertices around a face be selected without the face selected?

Tags: mesh, selection-tools

Oftentimes I like to make the edges of a beveled object use a separate material than the actual object itself.  For example, the bevel on a table, a picture frame, or a door frame might be different than the material in the center.

When I select the adjacent faces around an object — as seen on the left — the middle face is always selected.  This means that I cannot set the middle face's texture to something other than its surrounding faces.  On the right is an example of what I want, achieved with face-select mode.  Unfortunately, it doesn't work with vertex groups.
[image: Selecting adjacent faces auto-selects the middle one]

I need a straightforward way to set different materials under these circumstances in one object.

Comment: You don't need to be in vertex select mode to apply a material, you can select the four faces as you show and apply a material to them or select the one internal face and apply a material to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it selects the middle face as well is because you are in vertex select mode. To select the outer faces without selecting the middle one, switch to face select mode [image] and do so (you can cycle through the selection modes with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>).  To select the loop (the vertices going around the middle face), you can hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> while right clicking on an edge.

[image]

Comment: Since the sides are equal, another trick could be to select one face and use _Select > Similar > Area_.

Comment: I specifically mentioned that it didn't work in face-select mode.  I got what I wanted by making two separate vertex groups that operated on the opposite sides of the face, then clicking the first vertex group which somehow merged them.  It's still not as straightforward as I was hoping for.  If it works for you, though, then I guess I must be doing something weird.

Comment: @Stopforgettingmyaccounts... It ___should___. Perhaps you simply added a plane and extruded in the sides? This will keep the bottom face and that will interfere.

Comment: You have a hawk's eye for troubleshooting.  That's exactly what I did ;).

Comment: @Stopforgettingmyaccounts... In the future, _Inset_ the face with `I`.